# Judge the project rating sonarQube

Tags: quality-assessment, static-analysis, sonarqube

I did install [sonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) and performed a project evaluation. The fact is, sonarQube gave me a global note (A) and percentages, like duplication of code %, comment %...

My question is, what is a good rating? Is this a 5% of duplication a good ratio? What about the % of comment line? What is the average on existing project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no golden standard for code quality statistics. Also older Stackoverflow [questions about code duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298272/how-much-duplicated-code-do-you-tolerate) shows these topics are very opinionated.

What good or bad statistics are will also differ per product and its complexity. Some might need more comments and or duplicate code.

I would not use sonarQube to just rate a project, but to use as a tool that signals issues over time. Focus on the trends and set goals like we do not want to add more code duplication, take actions and monitor them.

Increase or maintain a steady code quality over time instead of sayings its good or bad in this point of time.

[image]